# Regex bad \g escape

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have this Python3 regex:

```
i = "some string wow https://www.amazon.ca/product-product-name"
print(re.match(r'\^https:\/\/www.amazon.[\b"com","ca"](.*)\g', i))
```

I am getting this error:

```
sre_constants.error: bad escape \g at position 41
```

The code should match https://www.amazon.ca/product-product-name.

Comment: Did you mean `/g`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, thanks.

Comment: What are you escaping exactly? Why do you escape the harmless forward slashes, but don't escape the periods?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm trying to escape the forward slashes in the url (`https://`). It should look like this, right?

`\^https:\/\/www\.amazon\.[\b"com","ca"](.*)/g`

Comment: @W.Reyna but `/` matches the character `'/'` verbatim, there is no reason to escape it, whereas the period `'.'` matches every character, and should therefore be escaped. Have you previously worked with sed?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have not previously worked with sed (which is why I'm having a hard time). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @W.Reyna No, I didn't mean it that way. It's not necessary to know `sed` to work with regex in Python. I just tried to infer why you thought that you had to escape the forward slashes.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Ah. I was using a regex tester, and when it gave me `Unescaped forward slash`, I thought it meant it wouldn't match `//`

Comment: @W.Reyna, In some languages/flavors, the forward slash needs to be escaped. Whether a regex tester (like regex101) shows an error message or not depends on what flavors it supports or currently selected by you. Apparently, in python, a forward slash doesn't need to be escaped. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/EFbCuv/1) vs [this](https://regex101.com/r/kRmObY/1) and notice the selected flavor at the left.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Interesting comparison. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here:

```
i = "some string wow https://www.amazon.ca/product-product-name"
print(re.findall(r'https://www\.amazon\.(?:com|ca)/(?:[^\s]+)', i))
```

prints:

```
['https://www.amazon.ca/product-product-name']
```

[Link to interactive demo](https://regex101.com/r/y5CXr8/1).